# expected value of vector

Tags: expected-value, variance

$X = [X_1X_2]^T$

$M = [ 1   $     $2]$$^T$ $∑$ = $[3$    $1,$
$1$ $4]$

$∑_{11} = 3 $  $∑_{12} = 1 $ $∑_{21} = 1 $ $∑_{22} = 4 $

I couldn't write as a matrix

$E[X^TX]$ = ?

I found  $E[X_1^2+X_2^2]$
these are not independent, I think I cant write $E[X_1^2]+E[X_2^2]$
How I can continue?

Answer (score 1):

$E(X+Y)=EX+EY$ is true whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are independent.